# Assigning Beds to Rooms in java

Tags: java

I have an assignment problem that I need some help with. It's modeling a retirement home, where we need to assign patients to beds and then beds to a room and then to a ward. The rooms can hold differing amounts of beds, either 1, 2, or 4.

I have assigned patients and their data to beds in the below class

```
public class Beds 

    protected int bed;
    protected Patients patient;
    protected boolean occupied;
    
    protected int totalBeds;
    
    protected static ArrayList<Beds> beds = new ArrayList<Beds>();
    
    protected Beds(int Bed, Patients Patient, boolean Occupied)
    {
        this.bed = Bed;
        this.setPatient(Patient);
        this.occupied = Occupied;

    }

    public int getBed()
    {
        return bed;
    }
    
    public boolean getOccupied()
    {
        return occupied;
    }
    
    public Patients getPatient() 
    {
        return patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patients patient) 
    {
        this.patient = patient;
        occupied = true;
    }
    
    public void assignBed(int oldBed, int newBed)
    {
        if ( !beds.get(newBed).getOccupied())
        {   
            beds.get(newBed).setPatient(patient);
            beds.get(oldBed).setPatient(null);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry that bed is taken. Please try again");
    }       
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return new String( "bed = " + bed + "patient = " + patient + "occuplied = " + occupied);
        
    }
}
```

The problem is coming from trying to then assign the beds to rooms of varying sizes.

```
public class Rooms 
{
    protected int roomNo;
    protected int totalBeds; 
    protected boolean full;

    protected static ArrayList<Rooms> rooms = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
    protected ArrayList<Beds> beds = new ArrayList<>();
    
    protected static Beds beds;
    
    public Rooms(int RoomNo, int totalBeds, ArrayList<Beds> Beds, boolean Full) 
    {
        this.totalBeds = totalBeds;
        this.roomNo = RoomNo;
        this.full = Full;
        this.beds = Beds;
    }
    
    int getRoomNo()
    {
        return roomNo;
    }

    int getTBeds()
    {
        return totalBeds;
    }
    
    boolean getFull()
    {
        return full;
    }
    
    ArrayList<Beds> getBeds()
    {
        return beds;
    }
```

The problem is I have been unable to figure out how to assign the beds from the bed class to work with the room class and I've been coding in circles for hours.

Comment: I think what's confusing you is that you use plurals in your classes, like Beds and Rooms. Rework your code to have a class to represent a single thing, so Bed, Room and Patient. A Room contains a list of Bed. A Bed may contain a Patient or not. I think that may make it easier to reason about.

Comment: What is your algorithm for assigning patients to beds in a room? I can think of a couple: arrange the patients to fill the rooms close together first (easiest on the nurses) or assign the patients one to a room until there are more patients than rooms (best on the patients).

Comment: The patients are assigned bed 1, then bed 2, and so on. Then bed 1 is assigned to room 1. Bed 2 and 3 are assigned to room 2. Beds 4, 5, 6, and 7 are assigned to room 3 and so on for a set number of beds, But a nurse can then move a patient to any bed in any room at anytime

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you remove the class Beds ?

You would have a class Bed, a class Room and a class Patient

The class Room has an attribute: arraylist of Bed

The class Patient has an attribute: Bed (you can also add a Room attribute)

The class Bed has an attribute: Patient (you can also add a Room attribute)

Then you instanciate your classes: Room_1, Patient_1, Bed_1...
And you fill the attributes with your objects: Room_1.add(Patient_1, Room_1) or Patient_1.room = Room_1

Does it answer to your question?